# What kind of Plugin is the New Playstation Share Blog using | Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, blogs

Love this feature http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ Users are able to post requested features and then vote them up or down. Is this a plug-in that can be downloaded?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 3):

Well if you took 5 seconds to look at the source (all resources from wp plugins are served out of thier respective directory) you would see this is indeed a plugin. It is called [wp-postratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/)

Comment: Sorry if I come off as brusque. I am a little edgy today!

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** Byron Whitlock points out which plugin they're using. Looks like they did a lot of customising, though.

You might consider saving yourself the implementation work and just using [Google Moderator](http://www.google.com/moderator/)...

Answer (score 1):

It is using the wp-postratings plugin, however, I will say that it isn't extremely modified.  The only thing we changed was fixing some bugs with binary (up/down) voting.  Everything else is handled via added rewrite rules and wp_query filters.